# Define members that must be attributes into the data contract

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, datacontract, datacontracts

Ok, I'm sure this must be terribly easy, but I cannot find info into the matter.

Also, it's my first time using WCF, so get easy on me if I'm a bit slow understanding things.

Let's say I have this class

```
[DataContract]
public class whatever {

    [DataMember]
    public string whateverName;

    [DataMember]
    public string whateverId;

}
```

This will serialize into:

```
<whatever>
    <whateverName></whateverName>
    <whateverId></whateverId>
</whatever>
```

How can I change it to make the following serialization?

```
<whatever whateverName="" whateverId="" />
```

Comment: http://blog.dlwelch.com/?p=924

Answer (score 1):

You can use below mentioned code like

```
[DataContract]
public class whatever
{
  [XmlAttribute]
  public string whateverName;

  [XmlAttribute]
  public string whateverId;
}
```

Comment: Please, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779824/wcf-xmlserializerformat-doesnt-parse-class-type for further explanation on the whole problem